# Reflection from Java to Swift

Tags: java, swift

Creating class instances in Java from string is not difficult, but I'm new to swift and do the same thing in that language is very hard for me.

**MOTIVATION:**

I need to call unknown controllers and its unknown methods (MVC)

**Java**

```
String className = "MyClass";
String methodName = "MyMethod"; // with one argument like (String[] args) and return String

// in swift can be a Dictionary
String[] argument = new String[] {"A", "B"}

Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Object instance = clazz.newInstance();

Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, Class<?>[]);

Object returnStringObject = method.invoke(instance, argument);
```

My attempt in **Swift**

```
let clazz: AnyClass? = NSClassFromString(className)

if clazz != nil {
    // ERRORRRRRR (use of unresolved identifier NSSelectorFromString)
    let selector: Selector = NSSelectorFromString(methodName)

    // ERRORRRRRR (cannot invoke performeSelector with an argument list of type selector)
    clazz?.performSelector(selector)
}
```

How can I do the same thing from Java to swift

Comment: the selector line should not actually cause an error. BUT the second error is justified since you currently only hold the class reference, not an instance. What you are missing for now is the equivalent of the `clazz.newInstance()`.

Comment: @luk2302 Do u can post an example? unfortunately there are no such examples for swift like what I posted in java.

Comment: are all classes that can be passed in subclass of NSObject?

Comment: @luk2302 Yes, all classes extends another that extends NSObject. Example: ► SomeClass: GlobalClass {} and GlobalClass extends NSObject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following might work for you:

```
let cla = NSClassFromString(className)
if let cla = cla as? NSObject.Type {
    let selector: Selector = NSSelectorFromString(methodName)
    let instance = cla.init()
    if (instance.responds(to: selector)) {
        print(instance.perform(selector))
    } else {
        print("method not found")
    }
} else {
    print("class not found")
}
```

Note that it would probably make things a lot easier and type safer to simply have a map / dictionary of `[String:ControllerInstances]` from which you can select your target controller. That way your controllers can have more complex initialisers and you will have one managed instance of each, not creating them over and over again.